# Responsive JQuery mobile dropdown menu on header is hiding under panel

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Dropdown menu is working fine on the content page.
But when it comes to panel, panel is sliding over menu.

I am using jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js and ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu to implement the menu functionality.

Here is the code:

test.html

```
            <table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle:none" class="ui-responsive" border="0" style="overflow-y:visible !important;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:right; width:80%;"></th>
                        <th style="text-align:right; width:20%;overflow-y:visible !important;">
                            <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper demo-1" style="overflow-y:visible !important;">
                                <button class="dl-trigger" id="menuButton">
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dl-menu">
                                    <li align="left">
                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li align="left">
                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Settings</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li align="left">
                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Logout</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul> 
                            </div>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Altay, thanks for organizing the content of post. Please answer it, If you know the solution.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue?